# Retail Kit - WebPOS cannot check out products

Tags: magento-1.9, plugin, inventory, pos

I've been exploring **Magento** at work recently and I've come across a **roadblock**.

**WebPOS** would tell me to

> "Please check your network connection. Or disable checkout online to
>   continue"

when I'm checking out in **online mode** and when I try checking out in **offline mode** it checks out and prints the receipt but fails to sync 15 seconds later and sends 2 object errors.

After checkout @ offline mode
[image: After checkout @ offline mode]
Offline Mode errors
[image: Offline Mode errors]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**: It seems like the only choice I have in the Location of **POS** is "Default Location" even after I add new warehouses in the Inventory Management module. Is it possible that it has something to do with the integration between the two modules?